# Ask for an input. if input is not a str, ask again

Tags: python, input

To sum up, I need to ask a question:

If the user doesn't introduce a str, I need the question to be asked repeatly until the use enter a str.

This is what I got so far.

```
x = input('What is your name? ')

if x != str
    x=input('Sorry, you need to introduce a str. What is your name? ')
```

Comment: Input is always str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you mean is that if the user doesn't input all *letters*, the program will keep asking for the user's name. You can use the method [isalpha()](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjbpoT53u3pAhVKnOAKHe8fCgsQFjAAegQIARAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpython-reference.readthedocs.io%2Fen%2Flatest%2Fdocs%2Fstr%2Fisalpha.html&usg=AOvVaw3u8OUw8SR1O-bfFTnHli1-) for that:

```
x = input('What is your name? ')

while not [s.isalpha() for s in x.split()] == [True for s in x.split()]:
    x = input('Sorry, you need to introduce a str. What is your name? ')
```

Comment: thats it! Thank you very much

Comment: but what if the user introduces name and surname ? if he introduces the space it doesn't work

Comment: I updated the answer to include surnames.